# Приложение крашится при чтении из файла

Tags: java, android

Специально проверял весь код, только с этим фрагментом происходит краш.

```
void read(){
    Identif = this.getResources().getIdentifier("@missions/Q_" + Level, "string", this.getPackageName());
    Text.setText(Identif);
    Level++;
}
```

Прошу помочь разобраться с этой проблемой.

Log

```
01-27 22:53:13.324 1026 1026 W     System com.EVALGames.Hospital                ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.EVALGames.Hospital-1/lib/arm64
```

Comment: Нужны логи. И попробуйте воспользоваться дебаггер от

Comment: @JVic ну вот, добавил

Comment: Это логи? Где stack trace? Где exception?

Comment: Вы уверены, что Identif это текст?